# Where is the best place to add custom settings in Timer trigger for Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

If I need to add some custom settings that my function(s) need to read in order to operate, where can I add them?

I am working with Visual Studio, I already created a project. I can see `host.json` and `local.settings.json` but not sure if I need to add in either or maybe in some other settings file.

---

Also when I don't have Program.cs or Startup.cs how can I make those settings visible in the function?

Comment: [Configure function app settings in Azure Functions | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help, I need to do that from Visual Studio.

Comment: I guess I should go for local.settings.json. Thanks.